# What's a good way for entity class inside a WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf, entity

I have a entity class inside a WCF project. There are 2+ services (.svc) that use that entity class.
When the client side access those services, and somehow the client access the 2 services and need to work with both entities (like comparing..). But even if the entities are the same, they are not compatibles at client side.

One way is to do DTO = Data Transfer Object. Is there any better solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind coupling your client and server, then you can share the types between the two. Place the entities into their own class library, which the service will use.

Then, on the clients, add a reference to this same class library. In the "Advanced" tab of the "Add Service Reference" dialog, make sure that "Share all types" is checked.

Comment: can you explain me in a little more detail how to do this? It seems perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @Alan: did you try what I suggested first?

Comment: damn man..I tried =P hehe.
Look. I clicked in the advanced stuff, but I don't see how to add the reference to the entity. Ahhh maybe cause I created a folder to entities instead of a library =D. But I don't remember now, I think I had problems creating a library.

Comment: @Alan: click the "References" folder of your project and add a reference. Then do the "Add Service Reference".